# How to vertically rotate a text inside tbody element of a table?

Tags: html, rotation, css-tables

How to vertically rotate a text inside tbody element of a table?

All the examples are based on theader elements but for the tbody it's not working correctly.

I work with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The code to rotate in HTML is:

```
style='transform: rotate(90deg);transform-origin: left top 0;'
```

For example, if the text is in the right use `float: right;` to rotate in place.

Try this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
    .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e" rowspan="3" ><p style='transform: rotate(-90deg);'>Y Axis<p><br></th>
    <th class="tg-031e">CONTOUR</th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">MY GRAPH IS PLOTTED HERE</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">SCALE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">X AXIS</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that the width and height of the cell are not adjusted. Here is what I obtain: http://jsfiddle.net/grosfish69/dowagd2g/3/

Comment: If you want to rotate `YAxis` text. check edited answer.

Comment: I saw your code.you are trying to rotate `td`. to rotate text replace with this:`<td ><div><p class="rotate3">Y&nbsp;AXIS</p></div></td>`

Comment: Thanks! Yes it's working now. The only problem now is that the width of the cell is too large as if the text was not rotated. http://jsfiddle.net/grosfish69/dowagd2g/8/